# Implementar función de puntuación en código con namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una código como el siguiente:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Entrada = namedtuple('Entrada','a, b, c, d, e')
Tipo = namedtuple ('Tipo','X, Y, Z')
frase_etiqueta = [Tipo(X=Entrada
(a='1',
 b='1',
 c=0,
 d='hola mundo',
 e='hola mundo'),
 Y=['hola', 'mundo'],
 Z=[('hola', 'I'), ('mundo', 'N')]),
Tipo(X=Entrada
(a='2',
 b='2',
 c=0,
 d='la casa es grande y tendrá personas',
 e='la casa es grande y tendrá personas'),
 Y=['la', 'casa', 'es','grande','y','tendrá','personas'],
 Z=[('la', 'A'), ('casa', 'N'), ('es', 'VP'), ('grande', 'N'),('y', 'C'),('tendrá', 'VF'),('personas', 'N') ])]
```

Aquí, tenemos dos frases, la primera "hola mundo" no contiene verbos. La segunda "la casa es grande y tendrá personas" contiene dos verbos, uno en presente (VP) y otro en futuro (VF).

Deseo construir una función que asigne, para este código, 0 puntos a las frases que contienen 0 verbos y 2 puntos a las que contienen 2 o más verbos. La lista de posibles tipos de verbos pongamos que es `[VP, VF, VPAS]`.

He intentado esto:

```
for frase in frase_etiqueta:
    for comp in frase:
        total_points = 0
        if sum(comp[1] in {'VP', 'VF', 'VPAS'} >= 0:
            total_points += 2
        else:
            total_points += 0
```

Gracias.

EDICIÓN:

He hecho esto a raíz de la respuesta para conservar la variable `total_points`. Parece que funciona pero se agradecen comentarios.

```
for frase in frase_etiqueta:
    total_points = 0
    verbs = {'VP', 'VF', 'VPAS'}
    if sum(tipo[1] in verbs for tipo in frase.Z) >= 2:
            total_points +=2
    else:
            total_points += 0

    print (total_points)
```

Comment: Hola pyring, te he respondido pero no me queda claro las condiciones para puntuar, dices:  "0 puntos a las frases que contienen 0 verbos y 2 puntos a las que contienen 2 o más verbos", queda en el aire que hacer con las que tienen 1 verbo. En la respuesta asigno 2 puntos a cualquier frase que tenga verbos y 0 si no los tiene. Si quieres algo diferente aclara este punto, un saludo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no he especificado bien. La idea es conseguir una función que asigne puntos dependiendo del número total de verbos. Había pensado en, por ejmplo, asignar 2 puntos a aquellas que tienen dos o más verbos, y 0 puntos al resto. Aunque podemos pensar en otras opciones para la asignación de puntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las categorías gramaticales las almacenas en la tupla `Tipo.Z` por lo que debes iterar sobre ésta. Por otro lado el condicional ocasiona que cualquier frase (tenga o no verbos) tenga una puntuación de 2, ya que haces `>= 0`.

Usando compresión de listas sería algo así:

```
verbs = {'VP', 'VF', 'VPAS'}
total_points = [2 if sum(tipo[1] in verbs for tipo in frase.Z) >= 2  else 0
                                              for frase in frase_etiqueta]
```

Lo que nos retornará una lista con los puntos de cada oración: `[0, 2]`

Si quieres la puntuación de todas las oraciones sumadas simplemente:

```
verbs = {'VP', 'VF', 'VPAS'}
total_points = sum(2 if sum(tipo[1] in verbs for tipo in frase.Z) >= 2 else 0
                                                 for frase in frase_etiqueta)
```

Con lo que se obtendría `2` simplemente (0 + 2).

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla. La respuesta funciona a la perfección. No obstante, el problema es que el código que tengo está añadiendo puntos a una variable declarada más arriba y denominada total_points = 0. Dicha variable va acumulando los puntos asignados por diversas funciones, una de las cuales es la que estoy intentando implementar. Por lo tanto, la solución ideal pasaría por asignar puntos a la variable total_points dependiendo del número de verbos. ¿Bastaría con añadir un + delante del signo =? Por ejemplo, total_points += ...

Comment: He hecho algún cambio para conservar el total_points. Creo que funciona :) Muchas gracias por la respuesta que como siempre era de 10.

Comment: Exacto, en ambos casos (tanto si quisieras la lista como el entero como variable de salida)  bastaría con usar `total_points += sum(2 if sum(tipo[1]...` para usar una variable definida anteriormente como creo que haz hecho.